# How to combine information from two rows with ALMOST same name

Tags: r

I have data frame that contains many columns with almost identical names, like A and A...1 , B and B...1 and so on. I would like to combine these columns, such as A and A...1 become one column. All these columns contain 0,1 or NA, NA:s should be considered to be zeros (0). And so if column A is 0,0,1,1,NA and column A...1 is 1,0,0,0,1 combined_A should be = 1,0,1,1,1.  So the if any of these column elements are 1 in other column, they should be one in the combined column.

Here's some code to produce example

```
original_table <- data.frame(A = c(0,0,1,1,NA),B = c(1,1,NA,NA,1),A...1 = c(1,0,0,0,1),B...1 = c(0,1,0,1,1))
```

So the original table looks like this

```
A  B  A...1  B...1
0  1  1      0
0  1  0      1
1  NA 0      0
1  NA 0      1
NA 1  1      1
```

The desired output table would look like this after combining.

```
combined_table <- data.frame(combined_A = c(1,0,1,1,1),combined_B = c(1,1,0,1,1))  
combined_A combined_B
1          1
0          1
1          0
1          1
1          1
```

I'm fairly familiar with R, but i couldn't find any help for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split.default` to split based on common part in the column names. In this example, it seems we can find common columns by extracting the first letter of each column name.

```
substr(names(original_table), 1, 1)
#[1] "A" "B" "A" "B"
```

We use this to split columns and in each group use `pmax` to get max value in each row removing `NA`

```
as.data.frame(lapply(split.default(original_table, 
        substr(names(original_table), 1, 1)), function(x) 
        do.call(pmax, c(x, na.rm = TRUE))))

#  A B
#1 1 1
#2 0 1
#3 1 0
#4 1 1
#5 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

An other base solution :
find the normal column names:

```
initial_col <- str_extract(names(original_table),"[A-Z]")%>%
  unique()

> initial_col
[1] "A" "B"
```

then for all columns containing these names (`grep(col,names(original_table),value = T)`), make a row sum and tramsform it to binary output

```
sapply(initial_col,function(col){
  tmp <- original_table[,grep(col,names(original_table),value = T)] %>%
    rowSums(.,na.rm = T,1) 
    ifelse( tmp  > 0,1,0)
})


     A B
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 0 1
[3,] 1 0
[4,] 1 1
[5,] 1 1
```